# school prac: "screensaver"

Tags: bash

Still working on my Prac.  Thanks for the help for my previous question.

we are tasked with making a "screensaver" for a terminal window.

what i'm trying to do is while waiting for a key press, randomly generate a number which then picks one of several ASCII art pictures i will have added to the file.

what i have come up with so far kind of works but it will only regenerate another number after i press a key.    I'm wanting it to keep generating a number until i press a key and it then dumps me out of the loop.

```
while read -r -n1 key
do
    num=$(awk -v min=5 -v max=10 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(min+rand()*(max- 
min+1))}')
echo $num
case $num in
1)
    echo "hello"
    sleep 5
    ;;
2)
    echo "bye"
    sleep 5
    ;;
***and so on***
esac
done
```

i'm sure I've overlooked something simple. been in this chair for most of 7 hours today.

many thanks

EDIT:
found this [Output something (in a loop) until a key is pressed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314834/output-something-in-a-loop-until-a-key-is-pressed)

and have adapted it accordingly but i don't get a cursor back until last sleep 5 has finished running.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

num=$(awk -v min=5 -v max=10 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}')

case $num in
  1)
    echo "hello"
    sleep 5
    ;;

  *)
    echo "whats going on 'ere?"
    sleep 5 &
    wait $!
    ;;
esac


# In the following line -t for timeout, -N for just 1 character
  read -t 0.25 -N 1 input
  if [[ $input = "q" ]] || [[ $input = "Q" ]]; then
# The following line is for the prompt to appear on a new line.
    echo
    break 
  fi
done
```

Comment: found this.... 

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314834/output-something-in-a-loop-until-a-key-is-pressed

and it mostly works but i don't key a cursor back until the sleep command is finished. is there a way to make sleep interuptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.  Ended up with this

```
#!/bin/bash
tput civis
while true; do

num=$(awk -v min=5 -v max=10 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}')

case $num in
  1)
    clear
    cat ./s0.file
    sleep 3
    ;;
....
  *)
    clear
    cat ./s9.file
    sleep 3
    ;;
esac 


# In the following line -t for timeout, -N for just 1 character
  read -t 0.25 -N 1 input
  if [[ $input = " " ]] || [[ $input = " " ]]; then
# The following line is for the prompt to appear on a new line.
    echo
    break 
  fi
done
tput cnorm
```